# BingMap Migration from V7 to V8. Error : Uncaught TypeError: Microsoft.Maps.Point is not a constructor

Tags: jsp, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I am in the process of migrating BingMaps from v7 to V8.

Did the following change in JSP file:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="//www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol"></script>
```

I am getting the error in the below javascript code

```
this.anchorDots = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(10,6), this.anchorPins = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(18,30), this.anchorPinsText = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(18,30);
```

**Error : Uncaught TypeError: Microsoft.Maps.Point is not a constructor**

Could some one please help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your code doesn't access the Microsoft.Maps namespace outside of a function and that the function isn't triggered before the Microsoft.Maps namespace does, otherwise it won't be available. I recommend using the callback parameter of the map script URL to call your map load function. This will ensure that the map script is fully loaded before your code tries to access it.